# Longest sequence of moves by one player with the same piece?

Tags: fide, famous-games, records

I suspect the following game in the European Club Champioship between David Howell and Pentala Harikrishna set a number of records.

```
[title "Howell, David W L vs Harikrishna, Pentala"]
[fen ""]

1. e4 c5 2. Nf3 d6 3. Bb5+ Nc6 4. O-O Bd7 5. Re1 a6 6. Bxc6 Bxc6 7. d4 cxd4 8. Nxd4 Nf6 9. Nxc6 bxc6 10. c4 e6 11. Nc3 Be7 12. b3 Nd7 13. Be3 c5 14. Bf4 Qc7 15. Qd2 Rd8 16. Rad1 Ne5 17. Bxe5 dxe5 18. Qc2 O-O 19. Rxd8 Rxd8 20. Rd1 Rd4 21. Ne2 Rxd1+ 22. Qxd1 Qa5 23. a4 Qb4 24. g3 g6 25. Kg2 Kf8 26. Qd3 Qb7 27. Ng1 f5 28. f3 Ke8 29. Nh3 Qd7 30. Qxd7+ Kxd7 31. Nf2 Bd6 32. Nd3 Kc6 33. Kh3 a5 34. Kg2 Kd7 35. Kf2 Kc6 36. Ke2 Bc7 37. Nf2 Bd8 38. Nd1 Bg5 39. Nc3 Bc1 40. Nd1 Kd6 41. Kf1 Bd2 42. Ke2 Bc1 43. Kf1 Bd2 44. Kg2 Ke7 45. Kh3 Kd6 46. Nf2 Be3 47. Nd3 Bg5 48. Kg2 Be3 49. Kh3 Bg5 50. Kg2 Be3 51. g4 Bg5 52. Kg3 f4+ 53. Kf2 Bd8 54. Kg2 g5 55. Kh1 Bc7 56. Kg1 Kc6 57. Kf1 Bd6 58. Ke1 Bc7 59. Kd1 Bd6 60. Kc1 Bc7 61. Kb1 Bd6 62. Ka1 Bc7 63. Ka2 Bd6 64. Kb2 Bc7 65. Kc2 Bd6 66. Kd2 Bc7 67. Ke2 Bd6 68. Kf2 Bc7 69. Kg2 Bd6 70. Nf2 Be7 71. Nh1 Bd6 72. Kh3 Be7 73. Nf2 Bd6 74. Nd1 Be7 75. Nc3 Bd6 76. Nb5 Be7 77. Na7+ Kb7 78. Nb5 Kc6 79. Kg2 Bf8 80. Na3 Bd6 81. Nc2 Bc7 82. Na1 Bd6 83. Kh1 Bc7 84. Kg2 Bd6 85. Kf1 Bc7 86. Ke2 Bd6 87. Kd1 Bc7 88. Kc2 Bd8 89. Kc1 Bc7 90. Nc2 Bd6 91. Kb2 Be7 92. Ne1 Bd6 93. Ka3 Be7 94. Ka2 Bd6 95. Nd3 Bc7 96. Nf2 Bd6 97. Ka1 Be7 98. Kb2 Bd6 99. Kb1 Be7 100. Kc2 Bd6 101. Kd3 Be7 102. Ke2 Bd6 103. Kf1 Be7 104. h3 Bd6 105. Kg2 Be7 106. Nd3 Bd6 107. Kf2 Bc7 108. Ke2 Bd6 109. Kd2 Bc7 110. Kc2 Bd6 111. Kb2 Bc7 112. Ka2 Bd6 113. Ka1 Bc7 114. Kb1 Bd6 115. Kc1 Bc7 116. Kd1 Bd6 117. Ke1 Bc7 118. Kf1 Bd6 119. Kg1 Bc7 120. Kh1 Bd6 121. Nc1 Bc7 122. Na2 Bd6 123. Nc3 Be7 124. Nb5 Bf8 125. Na7+ Kb7 126. Nb5 Kc6 127. Kg1 Be7 128. Kf1 Bf8 129. Ke1 Be7 130. Kd1 Bf8 131. Kc1 Be7 132. Na3 Bd6 133. Nc2 Be7 134. Kd2 Bd6 135. Ke2 Be7 136. Kf2 Bd6 137. Kg2 Be7 138. Kh2 Bd6 139. Na1 Be7 140. Nc2 Bd6 141. Ne1 Be7 142. Nd3 Bd6 143. Nb2 Be7 144. Kh1 Bd6 145. Kg2 Be7 146. Nd1 Bd6 147. Nf2 Be7 148. Kg1 Bd6 149. Kh1 Be7 150. Kg2 Bd6 151. Kh2 Be7 152. Nd3 Bd6 153. h4 h6 154. Kh3 Bc7 155. Kg2 Bd6 156. Kf1 Bc7 157. Kg2 Bd6 158. Ne1 Be7 159. Kh3 Bd6 160. Kh2 Be7 161. Ng2 Bd8 162. Kh3 Be7 163. Kh2 Bd8 164. Kh3 Be7 165. h5 Bd8 166. Kh2 Be7 167. Kh1 Bd8 168. Kg1 Be7 169. Kf1 Bd8 170. Ke1 Be7 171. Kd1 Bd6 172. Kc1 Be7 173. Kb1 Bd6 174. Ka1 Be7 175. Ne1 Bd6 176. Nd3 Bc7 177. Nf2 Bd6 178. Nh3 Be7 179. Ka2 Kd6 180. Kb2 Kc6 181. Kc2 Kd6 182. Kd2 Kc6 183. Ke2 Kd6 184. Kf2 Kc6 185. Kg2 Kd6 186. Kh2 Kc6 187. Nf2 Bd6 188. Nd3 Bc7 189. Kh3 Bd6 190. Kg2 Bc7 191. Kf1 Bd6 192. Ke2 Bc7 193. Kd1 Bd6 194. Kc2 Bc7 195. Kb1 Bd6 196. Ka2 Bc7 197. Kb2 Bd6 198. Kc1 Bc7 199. Kc2 Bd6 200. b4 cxb4 201. Kb3 Bc7 202. c5 Bb8 203. Kc4 Bc7 204. Nc1 Bd8 205. Nb3 Bc7 206. Kd3 Bd8 207. Ke2 Bc7 208. Kf1 Bd8 209. Kg2 Bc7 210. Kh1 Bd8 211. Kh2 Bc7 212. Kg1 Bd8 213. Kf2 Bc7 214. Ke1 Bd8 215. Kd2 Bc7 216. Kc1 Bd8 217. Kb2 Bc7 218. Ka1 Bd8 219. Ka2 Bc7 220. Kb1 Bd8 221. Kc2 Bc7 222. Kd1 Bd8 223. Ke2 Bc7 224. Kd3 Bd8 225. Kc4 Bc7 226. Nc1 Bd8 227. Nd3 Bc7 228. Kb3 Bb8 229. Ka2 Bc7 230. Ka1 Bb8 231. Ka2 Bc7 232. Kb1 Bb8 233. Kc2 Bc7 234. Kb2 Bb8 235. Kc1 Bc7 236. Kd1 1/2-1/2
```

Starting from move 79 Harikrishna moved his bishop 46 times consecutively. Is this a record for a FIDE rated standard time control game?

As a follow up: By my reckoning (please correct me in the comments if I'm wrong) Harikrishna moved this bishop a total of 192 times. Is this also a record for a FIDE rated standard time control game?

Comment: Why wouldn't they just agree to a draw lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The record for most consecutive moves by a piece in a FIDE rated (it's FIDE at the least) event is **80 moves by a rook**, starting on move 67. It happened in the game [Yueh Wei Po- Arora](https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1417562) during the 37th Chess Olympiad. It was a draw in the end. This record is on Tim Krabbe's page for chess records of course.

```
 [Title "Yueh Wei Po-Arora, 37th Chess Olympiad, Turin Italy, 6/2/2006"] 
 [FEN ""]
 [startply "133"] 

1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 g6 3. Nc3 Bg7 4. e4 d6 5. Nf3 Bg4 6. Be2 O-O 7. O-O Bxf3 8. Bxf3 c6 9. Be3 Nbd7 10. Qd2 Qc7 11. a4 a5 12. Be2 e5 13. dxe5 Nxe5 14. f4 Neg4 15. Bxg4 Nxg4 16. Bd4 f5 17. Bxg7 Kxg7 18. Qd4+ Kg8 19. Rad1 Rad8 20. exf5 gxf5 21. h3 Nf6 22. Rfe1 d5 23. cxd5 Nxd5 24. Nxd5 Rxd5 25. Qc4 Qf7 26. Rxd5 cxd5 27. Qd4 Rc8 28. Rd1 Rc4 29. Qxd5 Qxd5 30. Rxd5 Rxf4 31. Rxa5 Rb4 32. Rb5 Rxa4 33. Rxb7 Rd4 34. Kf2 Rd3 35. Ke2 Rg3 36. Kf2 Rd3 37. b4 Rb3 38. b5 Kh8 39. b6 Kg8 40. g3 h6 41. h4 Kh8 42. Rb8+ Kg7 43. b7 Kh7 44. Ke2 Kg7 45. Kd2 Kh7 46. Kc2 Rb4 47. Kc3 Rb1 48. Kc4 Kg7 49. Kd5 Rb3 50. Ke5 Rb5+ 51. Kd6 Rb3 52. Kc7 Rc3+ 53. Kb6 Rb3+ 54. Kc5 Rb1 55. Kc4 Rb2 56. Kc3 Rb1 57. Kc2 Rb4 58. Kc3 Rb1 59. Kd4 Rb2 60. Ke5 Rb5+ 61. Ke6 Kh7 62. Kf6 h5 63. Kg5 Kg7 64. Kxh5 f4+ 65. Kg4 fxg3 66. Kxg3 Kh7 67. Kg4 Rb4+ 68. Kg5 Rb5+ 69. Kf6 Rb6+ 70. Ke7 Rb4 71. Kd7 Rb2 72. Kc7 Rc2+ 73. Kb6 Rb2+ 74. Kc5 Rb1 75. Kc4 Rb2 76. Kc3 Rb1 77. Kc2 Rb4 78. Kc3 Rb1 79. Kd4 Rb2 80. Ke5 Rb1 81. Kf6 Rb6+ 82. Kf7 Rb1 83. Ke7 Re1+ 84. Kd6 Rd1+ 85. Kc5 Rc1+ 86. Kb4 Rb1+ 87. Ka5 Ra1+ 88. Kb4 Rb1+ 89. Ka3 Rb5 90. Ka2 Rb4 91. Ka3 Rb1 92. Ka4 Rb2 93. Ka5 Rb1 94. Ka6 Ra1+ 95. Kb6 Rb1+ 96. Kc7 Rc1+ 97. Kd8 Rd1+ 98. Ke8 Re1+ 99. Kf8 Rf1+ 100. Ke7 Re1+ 101. Kf6 Rf1+ 102. Kg5 Rb1 103. Kf6 Rb6+ 104. Kg5 Rb5+ 105. Kg4 Rb4+ 106. Kf3 Rb3+ 107. Ke4 Rb4+ 108. Ke5 Rb1 109. Kd4 Rb2 110. Kc3 Rb6 111. Kc4 Rb1 112. Kd4 Rb4+ 113. Kc5 Rb2 114. h5 Rb1 115. Kd5 Rb2 116. Ke6 Rb1 117. Kf6 Rb6+ 118. Kg5 Rb5+ 119. Kg4 Rb4+ 120. Kf5 Rb5+ 121. Kf4 Rb4+ 122. Kg3 Rb3+ 123. Kf2 Rb2+ 124. Ke3 Rb3+ 125. Ke2 Rb2+ 126. Kd3 Rb3+ 127. Kd4 Rb4+ 128. Kc3 Rb1 129. Kd4 Rb2 130. Ke3 Rb1 131. Kf2 Rb2+ 132. Kf3 Rb3+ 133. Ke2 Rb2+ 134. Kd3 Rb1 135. Kd4 Rb2 136. Ke5 Rb1 137. Kf6 Rb6+ 138. Kf5 Rb5+ 139. Ke6 Rb4 140. Rf8 Rxb7 141. Rf5 Ra7 142. Kf6 Rb7 143. Kg5 Ra7 144. h6 Rb7 145. Kh5 Ra7 146. Rg5 Rb7 147. Rc6 1/2-1/2
```